# Read a value of open circuit or GND

Tags: ltspice, npn

I'm trying to make a circuit that have in input a "not connected" or "GND", and the output is a function of input.

For example if there is no connection, the outpur is 3.3V. If the input is connected to GND, the output is 0V.

I only can use analog elements. I have problems to simulte the "open circuit" with ltspice

Do you have ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The way I am reading this is your input is either 'floating' or GND.

The simplest way to do this is with simple logic gates:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f4NDxbm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This is a circuit using an AND gate. The truth table for this gate is as follows:

```
A  B    F
0  0    0
0  1    0
1  0    0
1  1    1
```

If you have input A as your 3V3, and input B as your signal, you can see that when your input is open circuit (not connected), due to the pull up resistor R1, you get a 1-1 condition on the AND gate. Looking at the truth table, this would give you a logic '1' output.

If your input was then connected to GND, the B input would then be low, giving the AND gate a 1-0 input. Looking at the truth table, this would make it a logic '0' output.

Your open circuit condition can be simulated with the switch SW1.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That's a good idea because in open circuit we have the pull-up who settle the voltage at 3.3V. If "B" is connected to GND,  the AND input is 0, and voltage in the resistor is 3.3V. The resistor doesn't disturbed

Comment: That is correct. For me, this would be the simplest approach. It is cheap, effective and uses a minimal amount of components.

Answer (score 0):

using the PNP  and NPN transistors to make the circuit

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fD2DM5.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: It may be a good idea to explain how the circuit works for the OP. Will be more useful to them and others who come across this question with a similar issue. An explanation to accompany a circuit is always a good idea.

Comment: I'll try to explain.
Let's assume Input is not connected, so PNP base is 3.3V. PNP is ON, but with the 10k and 47k the current can't make Q1 ON.So Output = 3.3 (because Q1 is OFF)
Let's assume Input is now connected to GND. PNP base equal to 2.7V. there is a current through the Q1, Q1 is now, and pull the output to 0V.
That's a good idea too. Thanks
Just one question, how did you choose your resitor values?